# How to add multiple provider tiles to leaflet map in a loop

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to generate a series of `addProviderTiles` to add to a `leaflet` map. Consider the case where the following vector is of the provider tiles I want added to my leaflet object.

```
providers <- c("Stamen.TonerLite", "Stamen.Watercolor", "CartoDB.Positron", "Acetate.terrain")
```

I've tried:

```
pTiles <- lapply(providers, addProviderTiles)
```

but I'm met with the error:

```
 Error in map$dependencies : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

In my application, I may have any number of either provider tiles or layers which I want to add to the map so it is important for the leaflet map to be generated automatically, and not be hard typed e.g.:

```
leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTile(x) %>%
    addProviderTile(y) ...
```

Comment: `addProviderTiles()` takes two arguments, `map` and `provider`. Within your `lapply` you are only giving the `provider` argument

Comment: Of course, I was using it within %>% originally... Silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
providers <- c("Stamen.TonerLite", "Stamen.Watercolor", "CartoDB.Positron", "Acetate.terrain")
map = leaflet()
for(i in 1:length(providers)){
    map = map %>% addProviderTiles(providers[i], group = providers[i])
}

map = map %>% addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = providers,
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))

map
```

Comment: I know this is the correct method, but I can't get the map to switch between layers. Is this working for you?

Comment: My bad. I had to specify group when adding the provider tile as well. Just updating it.

Comment: yep - I forgot that step too :)